# Getting the sum of sales per year MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the sales per year I have this code (please see below), that gets the column name and format it into (please see below). I have start date and end date I want to get the all the months between the two years. For example **start date = 01/01/2017** and **end date = 01/01/2018** I want go get the months between them and format it into **SUM(JAN_2017) AS JAN_2017, etc** and at the same time get the sum of all the months for the year 2017 and 2018.

[SCREENSHOT OF MY TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jruPe.png)

> THIS IS MY COLUMN NAME SAMPLE (PLEASE REFER TO THE SCREENSHOT):
>   **JAN_2017, FEB_2017 UPTO DEC_2017**
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT OF MY CODE:
>  
>   **SUM(JAN_2017) AS JAN_2017, etc.**

CODE:

```
$start = new DateTime($_POST["start"]);
$end = new DateTime($_POST["end"]);

$smonth = (int)$start->format('Y')*12+(int)$start->format('n');
$emonth = (int)$end->format('Y')*12+(int)$end->format('n');

$firstmonth = min($smonth, $emonth);
$lastmonth = max($smonth, $emonth);
$months = array();

for ($i = $firstmonth; $i <= $lastmonth; $i++) {
    $thism = new DateTime(sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', intdiv($i, 12), $i % 12));
    $months[] = strtoupper($thism->format('M_Y'));
}

$m_total = implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', 'SUM($1) AS $1', $months));
$m_average = implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', 'AVG($1) AS $1', $months)
```

);

Comment: have you tried `SUM` lol  Where is the SQL,  `SELECT SUM(sales) as some FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date_field)`

Comment: Here is the sql for getting the monthly sum: **$sql = "SELECT $m_total FROM temp_sg_screen_sto_72_mos_summary";** I dont have the sql for yearly sum

Comment: How can I get all of the months from Jan-Dec and sum each based on the year

Comment: This is classic reason not to store data in wide format. Your year/month should be saved in one or two indicator columns with data in adjacent, value columns (sales, price, etc.) all in long format -more maintainable, scalable, queryable, and efficient. Consider resdesigning schema. Remember columns are expensive, rows are cheap!

Comment: @Parfait I know but this is not my table this table is owned by a company i am working with so I cant alter the table please help me

Comment: I would highly advise you to reach out to that company to change this schema quickly and it will not take too long with `UNION` or loops. And then have them update application code accordingly. You will receive performance issues beyond complex querying if you do not normalize this table. You may receive an answer to this problem and then forget about this wide table and an even bigger one will hit you in near future. FIX NOW! Read [DBA guru's story here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3976)

Comment: @Parfait I will reach out but first i need to solve this problem. I need to get the the yearly sales its like a bandaid fix then once i presented this to them I will make sure to fix this